# How to show apple-touch-startup-image for iPad

Tags: ipad, jquery-mobile

I am using following line of code to show start_up image

```
  <!-- iPad (Retina, portrait) SPLASHSCREEN-->
<link href="@img_css_scpt/inreviewim_mobile/images/startup_n_icon_images/apple-touch-startup-image-1536x2008.png" media="(device-width: 1536px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
<!-- iPad (Retina, landscape) SPLASHSCREEN-->
<link href="@img_css_scpt/inreviewim_mobile/images/startup_n_icon_images/apple-touch-startup-image-1496x2048.png" media="(device-width: 1536px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
<!-- startup image for web apps - iPad - portrait (768x1004) -->
<link href="@img_css_scpt/inreviewim_mobile/images/startup_n_icon_images/IM_Startup_768x1004.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
<!-- iPad (landscape) SPLASHSCREEN-->
<link href="@img_css_scpt/inreviewim_mobile/images/startup_n_icon_images/apple-touch-startup-image-748x1024.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
<!-- iPhone (Retina) SPLASHSCREEN-->
<!-- 640x920 for retina display -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="@img_css_scpt/inreviewim_mobile/images/startup_n_icon_images/apple-touch-startup-image-640x920.png" />
<!-- iPhone 3GS SPLASHSCREEN-->
<link href="@img_css_scpt/inreviewim_mobile/images/startup_n_icon_images/IM_startup_320x460.png" media="screen and (max-device-width: 320px)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
```

**it is looking well for iPhone and iPhone retina but not working for ipad.**

Device: iPad

iOS: 3.2,4.1,4.2,4.3.2

Jquery mobile version: 1.1.0

Jquery: 1.7.1

Can any one help for me for this issue?

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the Retina landscape dimensions backwards, should be: 2048x1496 not 1496x2048

```
<!-- iPad (Retina, portrait) SPLASHSCREEN-->
<link href="@img_css_scpt/inreviewim_mobile/images/startup_n_icon_images/apple-touch-startup-image-1536x2008.png" media="(device-width: 1536px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />

<!-- iPad (Retina, landscape) SPLASHSCREEN-->
<link href="@img_css_scpt/inreviewim_mobile/images/startup_n_icon_images/apple-touch-startup-image-2048x1496.png" media="(device-width: 1536px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
```

Reference:

- http://lineandpixel.com/blog/ios-web-app-icons-and-startup-images
- https://gist.github.com/2222823

Related:

- [Mulitple "apple-touch-startup-image" resolutions for iOS web app (esp. for iPad)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687698/mulitple-apple-touch-startup-image-resolutions-for-ios-web-app-esp-for-ipad)