# iPad Web App Splash Screen Won't Work in Landscape Mode

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, web-applications

I've read countless threads, blog posts, and other documentation online about this, yet I cannot get it to work.  I've spent hours researching this and trying different things.

I'm trying to get a splash screen image to show for a web app on the iPad 2.  I'm not even concerned with the iPad 3 resolution yet.

These are the tags that I have:

```
<link href="images/splash_748.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" rel="apple-touch-startup_image">
<link href="images/splash_768.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

splash_748.png is 748x1024

splash_768.png is 768x1004

The portrait mode splash screen works just fine.  The landscape version will not show.  Does anyone have any ideas?  I've tried over a dozen different ways to do this.  None of them have worked.

I've been deleting the app and clearing Safari's cache each time I make an update.  Then I go back to the web page and send it to the home screen.  This seems to pick up changes in the images, so I can't imagine it's caching anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a mistake in it. Look at the end of the first line

```
rel="apple-touch-startup_image"
```

it should be

```
rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
```

notice the _ should be a -

Edit: Heres my code for iOS web apps - covers most eventualities and seems to work on most devices but don't hold me to it :)

```
<!-- iOS Device Startup Images -->
<!-- iPhone/iPod Touch Portrait – 320 x 460 (standard resolution) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/ios/iphone-startup-320-460.png" media="screen and (max-device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)" />

<!-- iPhone/iPod Touch (high-resolution) Portrait – 640 x 920 pixels -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/ios/iphone-startup-640-920.png" media="screen and (max-device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />

<!-- iPad Landscape 1024x748 -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="1024x748" href="images/ios/ipad-startup-1024-748.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)" />

<!-- iPad Portrait 768x1004 -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="768x1004" href="images/ios/ipad-startup-768-1004.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)"/>

<!-- iPad (high-resolution Landscape – 2048 x 1496 pixels ) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="2048x1496" href="images/ios/ipad-startup-2048-1496.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />

<!-- iPad (high-resolution) Portrait – 1536 x 2008 pixels -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="1536x2008" href="images/ios/ipad-startup-1536-2008.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />

<!-- iOS Icons -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/ios/icon-57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/ios/icon-72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/ios/icon-114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="images/ios/icon-144.png" />
```

Comment: Wow.  You nailed it.  I swear I checked all the obvious things, but I guess not.  This drove me crazy.  Thanks for catching my stupid mistake.

Comment: I tried this code. The landscape image still will not appear for me. Ideas?

Comment: same for me, not working. @Doug, did you find any fix? Thanks

Comment: how to do it for android

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="1024x748" href="Default-Landscape.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" />
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it doesn't work.

    `<link rel="apple-touch-startup_image" sizes="1024x748" href="images/splash_748.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="768x1004" href="images/splash_768.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" />`

Comment: have you tried moving the image to the root folder? I recall reading that somewhere (obviously it's not always required since your portrait view works, but might be worth a shot)

Comment: I'll try that next.  I do have the image sizes correct, don't I?  The landscape image is 748x1024 (basically the same image, 20 pixels moved to account for the status bar, and rotated 90 degrees clockwise).

Comment: well you rotate the content of the image, but not the image, right? so it's still taller than it is wide. numerically you are correct in sizes, but I just want to make sure 7** is the width for both

Comment: Yes, I have the content rotated.  Both are 7** pixels wide.  Moving the images to the root of the site did not fix the issue.  Still only working for portrait.

Comment: another shot in the dark, but what if you swap the tag order? or try this post that has gotten some upvotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687698/mulitple-apple-touch-startup-image-resolutions-for-ios-web-app-esp-for-ipad

Comment: I've tried swapping the tag order.  I've also been through everything posted in that post.  I spent over an hour going through that post earlier.  Thanks though.  Seems like I'm not crazy after all.

Comment: How odd. I think I would re-examine the file itself if none of these 'known' solutions are working for you...I had a client send me graphics a few times that would be re-sized by iPhoto...maybe your file has been subtly modified? can you post a link to your image?