# how to set apple-touch-startup-image for iphone5?

Tags: iphone, web-applications, iphone-5

I tried

```
<link href="Images/Default-568h@2x.png" sizes="640x1136" media="(device-width: 640px) and (device-height: 1136px)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

But it didn't work. And apple's interface guildline hasn't been updated for iphone5.

Anybody knows?Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1.Don't use "width=device-width" for viewport, use codes below:

```
<meta content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">
<meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable">
```

2.Prepare an image sized 640*1096, save as "Images/Default-568h@2x", add this code to your page's header:

```
<link href="Images/Default-568h@2x.png" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="640x1096">
```

Here's a demo, it's compatible with iPhone5:
https://github.com/openfibers/php-tot

Comment: Does the `sizes` attribute actually work on `<link>` elements? I thought you had to use media queries. [My solution](http://taylor.fausak.me/2012/09/20/iphone-5-web-app-startup-image/) uses media queries and works with all iOS devices.

Comment: sizes attrib really works. Just check out the demo and run it on 4 inch simulator or iPhone5, it will tell

Comment: Your demo does work, but `sizes` has nothing to do with it. The iPhone 5 is loading the last `<link>` targeted at it with media queries. If you listed `Default-568h@2x.png` above `Default@2x.png`, it wouldn't work. Case in point, you have `sizes="320x640"` instead of `sizes="320x460"`.

Comment: Any tips about media queries for iPhone5 will be grateful

Comment: The blog post I linked earlier ([iPhone 5 Web App Startup Image](http://taylor.fausak.me/2012/09/20/iphone-5-web-app-startup-image/)) explains the media query to match an iPhone 5. For posterity: `(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)`.

Comment: @OpenThread.. i have a question about it... i tried your above answer, its working when my web application run under iPhone 5, fine... but when i tried iPhone 4 its not working... how can i set both device startup image.? for example: when run web app in iphone 5 show imageforiphone5.jpg then when run iphone 4 run imageforiphone4.jp... any idea..??? thanks

Answer (score 3):

The startup image has no direct relationship with the letterboxing.

The solution is to just change the viewport to a different width than device-width or 320. Why? I don't know, it's really weird but if you just use the next viewport you don't get the letterbox.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320.1">
```

The **sizes** attribute on the **apple-touch-startup-image** is being ignored so if you want to provide more than one you need to use media queries.

Other solution is to just update the viewport using JavaScript when it's an iPhone/iPod 4".

More on the solution and the findings at http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone-5-ios-6-html5-developers#updatewebapps

Answer (score 1):

There is an official reference for this…
(even for iPhone 5)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Comment: This reference has nothing to do with my question, since I'm making web app