# iOS Web App Splash Screen not loading

Tags: html, ios, splash-screen

I've been trying to get a splash screen for my web app to appear on iOS devices. When i load up the app after adding it to my home screen I get a white screen and nothing loads. However if i move the meta tags below my icons and splash screens the app will load up fine but the splash screen will not load. The icons work for all devices no matter where the code is.

Below is the code that i have at the moment:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"/>


<!--iOS ICONS-->

<link href="https://baea7f48c88acedc0f88adbf93a90554fa064d59-www.googledrive.com/host/0B1QgF0628vPRfjZTZDQ5NE1Fb3J3bnlsLTJxVk93YmdiZlRDTzFPaXJoWnE1VFlWVlZPaVU/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" 
  rel="apple-touch-icon" 
  sizes="120x120" />

<link href="https://baea7f48c88acedc0f88adbf93a90554fa064d59-www.googledrive.com/host/0B1QgF0628vPRfjZTZDQ5NE1Fb3J3bnlsLTJxVk93YmdiZlRDTzFPaXJoWnE1VFlWVlZPaVU/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" 
  rel="apple-touch-icon" 
  sizes="152x152" />

 <link href="https://baea7f48c88acedc0f88adbf93a90554fa064d59-www.googledrive.com/host/0B1QgF0628vPRfjZTZDQ5NE1Fb3J3bnlsLTJxVk93YmdiZlRDTzFPaXJoWnE1VFlWVlZPaVU/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png" 
  rel="apple-touch-icon" 
  sizes="180x180" />


<!--iOS SPLASH SCREENS-->

<!--iPhone 5-->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" 
  href="https://baea7f48c88acedc0f88adbf93a90554fa064d59-www.googledrive.com/host/0B1QgF0628vPRfjZTZDQ5NE1Fb3J3bnlsLTJxVk93YmdiZlRDTzFPaXJoWnE1VFlWVlZPaVU/Default-portrait@2x~iphone5.jpg"
  media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) 
        and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"/>

<!--iPad, Landscape-->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" 
  href="https://baea7f48c88acedc0f88adbf93a90554fa064d59-www.googledrive.com/host/0B1QgF0628vPRfjZTZDQ5NE1Fb3J3bnlsLTJxVk93YmdiZlRDTzFPaXJoWnE1VFlWVlZPaVU/Default-Landscape~ipad.png"        
  media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) 
        and (orientation: landscape) 
        and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)"/>

<!--iPad retina, Landscape-->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" 
  href="https://baea7f48c88acedc0f88adbf93a90554fa064d59-www.googledrive.com/host/0B1QgF0628vPRfjZTZDQ5NE1Fb3J3bnlsLTJxVk93YmdiZlRDTzFPaXJoWnE1VFlWVlZPaVU/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png"   
  media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) 
        and (orientation: landscape) 
        and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"/>
```

The reason for the long href which includes google drive links is because I have the site on google dive for testing purposes. It basically represents the website address.

<--EDIT-->

Here is what the code looks like now I have renamed some of the files and moved them. I noticed that the google drive address was not needed.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"/>

<!-- iPhone ICON -->
<link href="App Icon/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" sizes="57x57" rel="apple-touch-icon">
<!-- iPad ICON-->
<link href="App Icon/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" sizes="72x72" rel="apple-touch-icon">
<!-- iPhone (Retina) ICON-->
<link href="App Icon/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" sizes="114x114" rel="apple-touch-icon">
<!-- iPad (Retina) ICON-->
<link href="App Icon/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" sizes="144x144" rel="apple-touch-icon">

<!-- iPhone SPLASHSCREEN-->
<link href="images/apple-touch-startup-image-320x460.png" media="(device-width: 320px)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iPhone (Retina) SPLASHSCREEN-->
<link href="images/apple-touch-startup-image-640x920.png" media="(device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iPad (portrait) SPLASHSCREEN-->
<link href="images/apple-touch-startup-image-768x1004.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iPad (landscape) SPLASHSCREEN-->
<link href="images/apple-touch-startup-image-748x1024.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iPad (Retina, portrait) SPLASHSCREEN-->
<link href="images/apple-touch-startup-image-1536x2008.png" media="(device-width: 1536px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iPad (Retina, landscape) SPLASHSCREEN-->
<link href="images/apple-touch-startup-image-2048x1496.png" media="(device-width: 1536px)  and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

The icons work fine on any device I try the app on. However the splash screen still will not work.

There is only one page that says HELLO WORLD!. When it is added to the home screen the icon works but the splash screen does not.

Comment: What device are you trying to load this on?

Comment: @hopkins-matt iPad Air 2 and iPod 5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [Marconi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10011893/4556503) on [Mulitple “apple-touch-startup-image” resolutions for iOS web app (esp. for iPad)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687698/mulitple-apple-touch-startup-image-resolutions-for-ios-web-app-esp-for-ipad), try these for the splash screen meta tags instead: (You'll still need to iPhone 6 & 6 Plus tags)

```
    <!-- iPhone SPLASHSCREEN-->
    <link href="apple-touch-startup-image-320x460.png" media="(device-width: 320px)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
    <!-- iPhone (Retina) SPLASHSCREEN-->
    <link href="apple-touch-startup-image-640x920.png" media="(device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
    <!-- iPhone 5 (Retina) SPLASHSCREEN-->
    <link href="apple-touch-startup-image-640x1136.png" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
    <!-- iPad (portrait) SPLASHSCREEN-->
    <link href="apple-touch-startup-image-768x1004.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
    <!-- iPad (landscape) SPLASHSCREEN-->
    <link href="apple-touch-startup-image-748x1024.png" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
    <!-- iPad (Retina, portrait) SPLASHSCREEN-->
    <link href="apple-touch-startup-image-1536x2008.png" media="(device-width: 1536px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
    <!-- iPad (Retina, landscape) SPLASHSCREEN-->
    <link href="apple-touch-startup-image-2048x1496.png" media="(device-width: 1536px)  and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

**Updated Demo:**

```
   <!-- iPad retina portrait startup image -->
   <link href="//placehold.it/1536x2008.png"
         media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
                and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
                and (orientation: portrait)"
         rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

   <!-- iPad retina landscape startup image -->
   <link href="//placehold.it/1496x2048.png"
         media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
                and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
                and (orientation: landscape)"
         rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

   <!-- iPad non-retina portrait startup image -->
   <link href="//placehold.it/768x1004.png"
         media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
                and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)
                and (orientation: portrait)"
         rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

   <!-- iPad non-retina landscape startup image -->
   <link href="//placehold.it/748x1024.png"
         media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px)
                and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)
                and (orientation: landscape)"
         rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

   <!-- iPhone 6 Plus portrait startup image -->
   <link href="//placehold.it/1242x2148.png"
         media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px)
                and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
                and (orientation: portrait)"
         rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

   <!-- iPhone 6 Plus landscape startup image -->
   <link href="//placehold.it/1182x2208.png"
         media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px)
                and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
                and (orientation: landscape)"
         rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

   <!-- iPhone 6 startup image -->
   <link href="//placehold.it/750x1294.png"
         media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px)
                and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
         rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

   <!-- iPhone 5 startup image -->
   <link href="//placehold.it/640x1096.png"
         media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px)
                and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
         rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

   <!-- iPhone < 5 retina startup image -->
   <link href="//placehold.it/640x920.png"
         media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px)
                and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
         rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

   <!-- iPhone < 5 non-retina startup image -->
   <link href="//placehold.it/320x460.png"
         media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px)
                and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)"
         rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

Comment: Just tried this out, but for some reason it is still not working. Maybe it has something to do with it being on google drive, but beyond that I have no idea what could be wrong. It just shows a white screen and then loads the home page of the app.

Comment: Well, I just tried one of those Google Drive URLs and got a 404

Comment: You tried one of the URLs that I poster or another?

Comment: I've tried several different versions of the code you suggested but can't get it working. I have added a link to the page I have been using to test in my original post. I have also added a link to my google drive file if you are interested in seeing the whole thing

Comment: @JamesBaker I had tried one of the original URLs in your splash page `link` tags. It resulted in a 404. I have tried the new one, but I believe you main issue may be dimensions. I have included a working example. You should be able to copy & paste it in and see a splash image. I would double check your image dimensions are correct.

Comment: Thanks, the demo you posted worked. I looked up the dimensions for the images and you were right they were off a bit, I had downloaded a template of the internet for them and it was slightly off.