# Web App after restoring iPhone 4 backup on iPhone SE has the iPhone 4 size

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-standalone-web-app, iphone-web-app

I am moving from iPhone 4 to iPhone SE.
I have a web app on my iPhone 4 that was added to the home screen.

After restoring iPhone 4 backup on the iPhone SE I see this Web App but its size is constrained to the size of the iPhone 4 screen while displayed on the bigger iPhone SE screen.

Is there any way to "recalculate" the size of the Web App without removing/installing it again?
I am using LocalStorage a lot in this web app and if I remove it from the home screen I will loose it all.

[image]

Comment: Do an "Upgrade". Your local storage will not be lost during an upgrade. If you do a reinstall, you lose it all. Backup everything before testing.

Comment: well this is my plan B but I was looking for the A one ;) which is to ask iOS to refresh the app size for me.

Comment: Or maybe I don't understand what you mean by upgrade. Do you mean there is a way to Upgrade a web app as a standard iOS function or you mean that the web app should have support for the Upgrade operation? I was playing around with the app settings in HTML (like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`) but the app size is constrained on another level (not in the app itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently when you add a Homescreen bookmark - you get a simple iOS app (with a single WebView probably) which is not converted when you restore if from backup on a device with bigger screen.

In my case I had to reinstall it on my new device in order to have a full screen app version.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a startup image for your web app? The last time i worked on a web app (some years ago) I discovered that the startup image resolution decides the resolution for the rest of the app(!).

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687698/mulitple-apple-touch-startup-image-resolutions-for-ios-web-app-esp-for-ipad) for startup image HTML syntax for multiple devices.

I hope this helps.

Comment: No I don't ... will try to add one.